# fancyhdr - Koch Snowflake as part of \headrule

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, tikz-decorations

I have redefined the \headrule to include part of the the Koch Snowflake from the \usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals} package. Here is my code and a screenshot:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\renewcommand\headrule{%
    \vspace{-0.75in}
    \hrulefill
    {\tikz[decoration=Koch snowflake]{\draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (3,-2) }}};}}
}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead[L]{Name:}
    \fancyhead[C]{Period:}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

First Page

\end{document}
```

[image]
My goal is to have the nth iteration of the snowflake corresponding with the nth page of my document (My document will only be around 5-6 pages). My idea is to use some type of for loop to do this. I'm imagining something similar to this, where I am redefining the headrule for each page.

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,final page}{%

\renewcommand\headrule{%

%%something with koch snowflake here%%

}

}
```

I think I need the number of decoration commands to be equal to \thepage. I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a complete example that works except for the Koch snowflake?

Comment: Sure! I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks! Cool question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can recursively define a macro that picks up a new `decorate` on each page. This is done with

```
\xdef\MyDeco{decorate{\MyDeco}}
```

in

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\setlength\headheight{16pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
    \vspace{-0.75in}
    \hrulefill
    {\tikz[decoration=Koch snowflake]{\draw \MyDeco;}}%
    \xdef\MyDeco{decorate{\MyDeco}}%
}
\xdef\MyDeco{decorate{ (0,-2) -- (3,-2) }}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead[L]{Name:}
    \fancyhead[C]{Period:}
}

\pagestyle{firstpage}

\begin{document}

First Page
\clearpage
Second Page
\clearpage
Third Page
\clearpage
Fourth Page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. Thank you! I haven't seen `\xdef` before, so I'll have to read up on it.